# What is Angular's SafeUrl

Tags: angular

The [documentation](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/SafeUrl) only says:

> Marker interface for a value that's safe to use as a URL linking to a document.

When should I use `SafeUrl`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You use `SafeUrl` along with `DomSanitizer` to tell the Dom that a URL is trusted by your app.

> Angular treats all values as untrusted by default. When a value is
>   inserted into the DOM from a template, via property, attribute, style,
>   class binding, or interpolation, Angular sanitizes and escapes
>   untrusted values.

For example, doing the following will result in an error:

```
<iframe [src]="iframeSrc"></iframe>
```

in your ts:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  iframeSrc: string;
  constructor(){
      let id = 's7L2PVdrb_8'; // Game of Thrones Intro Video
      this.iframeSrc = `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${id}`;
  }
}
```

> unsafe value used in a resource URL context

To avoid this, you use `SafeUrl` with `DomSanitizer` to tell you app that the dynamic URL you are using is trusted:

```
import { DomSanitizer, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

export class AppComponent  {
    iframeSrc: SafeUrl;
    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){
        let id = 's7L2PVdrb_8'; // Game of Thrones Intro Video
        let url = `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${id}`;
        this.iframeSrc = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
}
```

See this [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ohjb1b?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Is it possible to use bypassSecurityTrustUrl for a Post?