# iframe not loading src in angular4 application

Tags: angular, iframe, src

In my application i'm loading a youtube vedio into a iframe.
I have sanitized the url. But the src attribute doesnt load when i run the application.

below is the html:

```
<a [href]="data.url" target="_blank" *ngIf="data.contentTypeString=='YOUTUBE_VIDEO' && data.url != null">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                <iframe *ngIf="data.contentTypeString=='YOUTUBE_VIDEO'" 
                        class="embed-responsive-item" 
                        src="{{data.url}}"></iframe>
            </div>
        </a>
```

below is the screenshot when i run the same:
[image]

The src just wont load
i have tried with [src]=data.url.

Below is the method i'm using to sanitize the url:

```
public manageYoutubeUrl(url: any) {
        console.log("url====" + url);
        var youtubeUrl = this.sanitize.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url.replace('watch?v=', 'embed/').replace('http://', 'https://')+"?wmode=opaque&rel=0&autohide=1&showinfo=0&wmode=transparent");
        console.log("youtubeUrl=====" + youtubeUrl);
        return youtubeUrl;
    }
```

When i check the log for youtubeURL it's comming like this:

> youtubeUrl=====SafeValue must use [property]=binding:
>   https://www.youtube.com/embed/l-103taCWOQ?wmode=opaque&rel=0&autohide=1&showinfo=0&wmode=transparent
>   (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)
>
> ERROR Error: Required a safe ResourceURL, got a URL (see
>   http://g.co/ng/security#xss)
>       at DomSanitizerImpl.checkNotSafeValue (

Please guide.
Thanks.

Comment: it think it is down to `DomSanitization` issue @Shruti

Comment: See your console, is there an error? See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46303484/1791913

Comment: `[src]="data.url"`

Answer (score 6):

You need to do some thing like this

**TS**

```
 import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

 this.current_url=this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url)
```

**Template**

```
<iframe id="frame" frameborder="0" [src]="current_url"></iframe>
```

**Update After comment**

Just do some thing like `[src]="current_url"` or `[attr.src] = ""`

Comment: i have updated my question with the sanitiz method and error

Comment: then you just do some thing like `[src] = "url"`. you should update the question with the whole method as this is the first point of failure .

Comment: :I have done everything that you are telling but its still not working

Comment: try and use the embed url instead of the regular one `https://www.youtube.com/embed/video-ID` @ShrutiNair

Comment: I have the same problem as well.

Comment: save my time. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Works fine after using settimeout.

setTimeout(() => {
      this.current_url=this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url)
      }, 2000);

Comment: You should mention that `this.current_url=this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url)` needs to run in the constructor, and that the constructor's signature should be changed to: `constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer)`