# IONIC 4: ion-button loses its href attribute

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4

I have a slider with buttons as the following code, I am using the href attribute because I want to open an external link with google maps and facebook. All works well, but sometimes the buttons don't respond to the click events. I reviewed them with the chrome web inspector, and the href attribute dissapear from the button sometimes, until I restart the app.

```
<ion-slide *ngFor="let evento of eventosDespacho">
  <div class="flex-container-row">
    <ion-button
        color="secondary"
        expand="block"
        class="f-g-1"
        [href]="evento.link_transmision"
    >
      <ion-icon name="videocam"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>

      <ion-button
        color="secondary"
        expand="block"
        class="f-g-1"
        href="https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query={{
          evento.latitud
        }},{{ evento.longitud }}"
      >
        <ion-icon name="map"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </div>
  </ion-slide>
```

Comment: Is the url safe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46302873/what-is-angulars-safeurl

Comment: Now I sanitize my external urls, but I still have the same problem.

Comment: Any errors on console? Place `{{ evento.link_transmission }}` inside buttons that don't work, and show us what it prints.

Comment: No console errors, and if I print {{ evento.link_transmission }}, the url is correctly shown, but in the button the href attribute disappears. Also, when this error happens, the slider options, not work, for example, I have the auto and loop options activated, but when the error happens, the slider stops changing slide automatic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: The problem was the option "loop" in the ion-slides, I think it is a bug in the Ionic 4 framework. When I stop using loop, all works well.

I hope the Ionic team fixes them soon