# This document requires 'TrustedScriptURL' assignment in Angular 11

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, nginx, centos7

when I open my Angular app (angular version 11) in production environment(nginx 1.16.1, Os:Centos 7), it becomes a blank page in google chrome (Version 88.0.4324.150). I got these errors in my console.  but it works fine in Firefox.

[image]

in the other hand the app worked fine locally in windows 10 with the same version of nginx (1.16.1) and google chrome (Version 88.0.4324.150).
How can i fix the problem in production environment with chrome?
Any guide will be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: it seems like, you don't sanatize the url, thats why this is blocked by angular. 
To bypass /trust a URL you should look into this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46302873/what-is-angulars-safeurl#:~:text=1%20Answer&text=You%20use%20SafeUrl%20along%20with,sanitizes%20and%20escapes%20untrusted%20values.

Comment: i have no url in my angular code.