# How to pass an external variable to an Angular Iframe?

Tags: angular, iframe

I have created a simple Angular application and have it in production.
From another project I have invoked it through an iframe.

The iframe is displayed correctly, but I don't know how to pass a variable to the application that is inside the iframe.

I have tried this:

```
Parent App
<iframe src="https://{myBusinessUri}.amazonaws.com/index.html?id=12345"></iframe>

Iframe App > App.Module
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getQueryParam();
  }

  getQueryParam() {
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      const id = params['id'];
      console.log(id);
    });
  }
```

If I add the id to the iframe an error occurs.

```
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'index.html'
```

I also tried to put the query param id, in the path of the parent application but without success.

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46303484/6442841

Comment: does not help, there you are passing a path param, I want a query param that I want to read inside the iframe application @StPaulis

Comment: I still believe that is helpful. I am not the owner of that answer, but in both cases you ought to end up with a `SafeUrl`. In the example above you can see a working demo as well.

Comment: The problem is not caused by safeUrl, but by passing it a queryParam, without the queryParam the iframe loads perfectly. 
The question is more oriented to how to read a variable in an Angular application that is an iframe

Comment: `<iframe [src]="iframeSrc"></iframe>`, where `iframeSrv` is a SafeUrl of the string ``https://${myBusinessUri}.amazonaws.com/index.html?id=12345``